# Synonyme de complétion

Tags: choix-de-mot, vocabulaire

Je cherche une expression qui serait « l'action de compléter, remplir un formulaire ». J'ai vu à quelques endroits « complétion », mais il s'agit d'un faux-ami.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il y a ces deux possibilités : (sans prétention d'exhaustivité)

- **le remplissage d'un formulaire** est un peu inélégant (est-ce subjectif ? probablement) mais sera idéal dans un contexte informel : sans ambiguité.
- **le renseignement d'un formulaire** est un peu plus sophistiqué, mais pourra sembler moins clair que la première formulation, notamment à cause de la polysémie de *renseignement* (soit 1/ l'action de renseigner, soit 2/ une information utile)

Answer (score 3):

Habituellement on parle de [complètement](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9tion) (wikipedia), de [saisie semi-automatique](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=fr&answer=106230) (support google), ou de suggestions (ailleurs).

Remarquez que [le terme est déjà français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/completion), et il a plus un sens de finition que de suggestion. Il a même [deux synonymes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/compl%C3%A9tion), qui sont *accomplissement* et *achèvement*.

Remarquez encore que l'ambition de nombreux acteurs du web, qui ont popularisé cette fonction, google en tête, est bien l'accomplissement, et non seulement la suggestion ; l'usage du terme français n'est donc pas si erroné que ça, c'est simplement l'ambition des acteurs informatiques français qui est édulcorée par rapport à leurs homologues américains.

Voir par exemple [les explications de google](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=fr&answer=106230) sur cette fonction, qu'ils envisagent comme une prédiction, un confort, une prise de conscience des erreurs, une découverte d'informations utiles. Bien au delà, donc, du simple complètement.

Comment: Qui a parlé de web ou de google ? Je ne pense pas que la question portait sur ce sens là.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Oui, ok, mais la question parle de complétion de formulaires... comment faites-vous si vous n'êtes pas sur le web ?

Comment: J'en suis pas tout à fait sûr, mais le papier ça existe toujours non ?

Comment: Bon, je vais vous donner un peu de contexte: "[...]De déléguer des personnes responsables de la déclaration des événements, ainsi que de la **complétion** des formulaires de diffusion, de redressement et de suivi;[...]

Comment: Bon... ok, ok, ok. Mais, à part ça, ma réponse est juste, non ?

Answer (score 0):

En complément de la réponse de Romain Valeri, voici une liste de [synonymes de « complétion »](https://lebonsynonyme.fr/synonyme/compl%C3%A9tion) (par nombre de votes sur le site source) :

- accomplissement
- achèvement
- réalisation
- renseignement
- remplissage
- saisie

Answer (score -1):

Selon l'Académie française, l'usage de "renseignement" dans ce contexte est inapproprié : http://www.academie-francaise.fr/renseigner-un-formulaire